# Making a AJAX rule work using a .htaccess rule work over HTTPS

Tags: html, ajax

Thanks for reading this...

I have a search form on my site which uses javascript to spit out the results and places those results in their own directories.

This the .htaccess which makes that happen:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+/.+ courses.php [L]
#RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The above works great by placing the results in the appropriate file structure but it breaks when I am using https. Our certificate is correctly installed - I just figure that the above .htaccess might be breaking the HTTPS since it is over another port...

Any ideas where to begin here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it -

Simply all resources had to be https

Easy enough....